# IUBH university Msc can give a chance to have a phD in germany?

Tags: phd, germany

I came accross a Masters of Data Science from the online [IUBH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUBH_University_of_Applied_Sciences) university in Germany.

Would this degree grant me the chance to pursue a PhD in Germany? or will it be looked over as a weaker university or a degree with little research experience ?
and if not, does anyone know a better program that would help me through this ?

some background information about me:

I have started working in Germany in the Hardware sector for about 3 years. Almost a year ago i switched to Data Science because i felt i much more motivated working in that discipline. I have a Bachelor of engineering degree which had me study 5 years, granted me the ability to work in Germany (since it has more credits than a Bachelor of science engineering degree) but not a masters degree. It has always been a goal of mine pursuing a PhD, but unfortunately i cannot pursue a Master's degree in Germany without leaving my full time job, which i need to support my family.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IUBH is not a university, but a "Fachhochschule" (somewhat misleadingly translated as "University of the Applied Sciences" into English). The expected qualification for enrolling into PhD studies at a German university is have a Master from a university. While exceptions to this are possible, degree programmes at Fachhochschulen are meant to prepare for work in industry, not in academia.

The leading distance-learning university in Germany is the FernUniversitaet Hagen (https://www.fernuni-hagen.de/). Their MSc degrees should fully qualify your for subsequent PhD studies. (I am a Hagen-alumnus, and went on to do a PhD in Cambridge after getting my MSc Computer Science from Hagen).

Comment: I've had some experience working with people at FernUniversitaet Hagen (also in CS) and recommend them highly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that really helps me a lot. I checked their programs and they only have computer science in german after having a C1 level.
That is really much higher than my current level. do you happen to know any other programs that might offer this in english ?

Comment: @anxiousPI There is no reason to do a degree at a German university in order to be admitted for a PhD if you are planning to do it remotely anyway.  Note that it might also be possible to be admitted for a PhD with only a bachelor's degree (though very likely you would be obliged to take some extra courses and/or hand in a master's thesis).

Comment: Arno, I think I remember reading about you on the news, very impressive. I can personally vouch for the mathematics master as well (which is better suited for someone wanting to become a data scientist probably), their course material is imo. better than that of most other German universities. Since a masters degree is basically required to start a PhD in Germany and Hagen is the only remote option I'm aware of that is fully recognized, rigorous and cheap I think @anxiousPI will have to bite the bullet and become fluent in German.

Comment: Sorry but your answer is incorrect. You can do a PhD in Germany with a Masters from a University of Applied Sciences, legally they are the same kind of degrees as Universities. You only need to make sure that is is a scientific Masters program, there are many of them around Germany.